# How to enable and disable a component?

Tags: android

How do you enable and then disable a component from the manifest in the java code?

Answer (score 2):

taking Pawan approach to more generic implementation:

```
public static void setComponentState(Context context, String packageName , String componentClassName, boolean enabled)
{
    PackageManager pm  = context.getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(packageName, componentClassName);
    int state = enabled ?  PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED :  PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED;
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,
            state,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

}
```